# Generation of a nonlinear semi group

Tags: operator-theory

Let $H$ is a Hilbert space

let $A:D(A)\subset H \rightarrow H$ a nonlinear operator.

$I:H\rightarrow H$ is the identity operator ($I(u)=u$).

if we suppose that $A-cI$ generates a nonlinear semi group of contaraction. Can we say that $A$ generates a nonlinear semi group of contarction.

$c$ is a strictly positive constant.

Comment: The answer is **no**. Take $H = \mathbb{R}, A(x) = c/2 \cdot x$ (linear).

Comment: Please give your definition of the generator. For some people the generator of $(e^{tA})$ is $A$ and for some it's $-A$, i.e., there are differing sign conventions.

Comment: Hans Engler..I forgot to say that H is a Hilbert space.

Comment: MaoWao..I mean A

Comment: Then Hans Engler's comment gives counterexample.